# how do we tell where a django redirect comes from

Tags: python, django

I would like to put in an error line if someone goes to a page that requires authentication.  In the view, I have used the `@login_required` decorator.

In settings I have the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/login/'` setting set in the settings.py file.

In the view, if there's an error, I put in the reason in the data path:

```
data = {}
data['error'] = "Login not correct.  Please try again."
data['csrf'] = csrf_protect
return render(request, "public/auth/login.html", data)
```

How do I determine when the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL is the cause to come to this view when executed by the `@login_required` decorator?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, if you were redirected by `@login_required` decorator, the `next` query parameter is added to the path. For example:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/login/?next=/profile
```

So you can check if `next` is in the `request.GET`.

Comment: That was perfect.